# Office 2007 32 bit to Office 2010 64 bit upgrade

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-office, upgrade

I have Office 2007 32 bit installed. I want to install 2010 64 bit.

I understand there is no direct upgrade. I have to uninstall and then install 2010.

Is there a way to save all my settings, account info etc. before uninstalling?

There was a settings migration wizard in Office 2003, it seems gone from 2007.

Comment: Not really an answer, but when I migrated, it picked up all my settings in Outlook 2010 from 2007 even after uninstall. Of course I backed everything up first, but on first run of 2010 everything was already there. I guess the uninstaller didn't touch the AppData folder or something.

Comment: I'm curious about what "settings" you want to migrate? I don't think I've *ever* needed or wanted to configure anything....... actually, I'm thinking of just Word. Maybe the other office tools need some tweaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your settings are stored in your Windows profile directory.  Even if you uninstall and reinstall Office, your profile is left untouched and will be used again when you install and run the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Tread carefully - if you want to upgrade from 32-bit Office 2007 to 64-bit Office 2010 without reinstalling Windows, you might hit some technical road-blocks; particularly if you have 3rd party applications installed on your computer that interact with Office.

If you end up reinstalling Windows before installing Office 2010 64-bit (my recommendation if you must upgrade), you will need to be all the more careful and particular about manually reinstating your preferences and settings after the Windows/ Office installation.  If you choose this option, you should either be extremely careful to back up all your files including the C:\Users folders (where Outlook data are stored in .pst files); or else, you should install Windows/ Office on a new hard drive and transfer your files from the old one as required.

http://www.slyman.org/blog/2010/11/64-bit-windows-7office-2010-migration-experiences/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Migration Wizard is gone, and the functionality was transfered to Windows Team, according to Microsoft blogs.

You haven't written which Windows version you are using, but in Windows Vista/Windows 7 there's a tool called "Windows Easy Transfer" under "Start/Accessories/System Tools" which seem to transfer some of the settings.

You may also try "User State Migration Tool", which can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=799ab28c-691b-4b36-b7ad-6c604be4c595&DisplayLang=en).

[What Does USMT Migrate?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560792%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_3)